# When slabtop shows USE 0% but ACTIVE is nonzero, should I be worried or is it just a bug?

Tags: linux, memory, monitoring

Start of my `slabtop -sc` looks like this

```
Active / Total Objects (% used)    : 3305074 / 4014163 (82.3%)
 Active / Total Slabs (% used)      : 110077 / 110077 (100.0%)
 Active / Total Caches (% used)     : 110 / 149 (73.8%)
 Active / Total Size (% used)       : 509560.16K / 604881.95K (84.2%)
 Minimum / Average / Maximum Object : 0.01K / 0.15K / 16.75K

  OBJS ACTIVE  USE OBJ SIZE  SLABS OBJ/SLAB CACHE SIZE NAME                   
3127215 2458622 0%    0.10K  80185       39    320740K buffer_head
144984 143761   0%    0.57K   5178       28     82848K radix_tree_node
 58957  38287   0%    1.07K   2033       29     65056K ext4_inode_cache
116337 115833   0%    0.20K   6123       19     24492K vm_area_struct
 76461  75955   0%    0.19K   3641       21     14564K dentry
  1335   1322   0%    9.62K    445        3     14240K task_struct
  3072   3030   0%    4.00K    384        8     12288K kmalloc-4k
```

I see that all these lines have "USE" value of "0%". **Is this something I should be worried about or is this just some kind of bug in `slabtop`?** I would have expected usage percentage to match computation result of `ACTIVE` divided by `OBJS`.

```
$ slabtop --version
slabtop from procps-ng 3.3.12

$ uname -a
Linux desktop 5.4.0-117-lowlatency #132~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jun 3 00:12:19 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: desktop…-lowlatency ? Does this mean you are running a RT-patched kernel ?

Comment: I'm using kernel with `CONFIG_PREEMPT` but not `CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT`. Ubuntu/Canonical supports this with pre-made packages with names starting `linux-lowlatency-hwe-`.

Comment: And my hostname is literally `desktop`. I prefer to keep things simple so my workstation is always `desktop` and my laptop is `laptop`.